# Why is Flash-related question do not take interest in SO?

Tags: discussion

I've noticed that Flash/Action-Script3 questions in SO do not take much interest even with the high popularity of Flash platform. Any specific reasoning?

for example: (these two questions were asked at the same time)

.Net related question, Views: 45

Flash relation question, Views: 8

Comment: I was originally going to [link this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193953/flash-cs4-refuses-to-let-go) as a counterpoint, but 40k views for 10 months on SO is actually... troublingly small. That could be blamed on creative liberties, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this has a specific reason. It's a simple question of numbers. There are simply more people interested in .NET around than there are people interested in Flash.

Also, look at the [tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags). There are about 60,000 questions tagged .NET; the numbers for the Flash related tags are way lower (and probably have a lot of overlap).

Comment: Any thoughts on *why* there are relatively few people around who are interested in Flash?

Comment: @MarkJ: thoughts? Sure. Flash attracts all kinds of folk, only some (perhaps a minority of whom) consider themselves programmers... and SO attracts MOSTLY programmers. And there are other popular places to ask Flash questions, as evidenced by any Google search on any Flash topic. .Net questions less. This is all pure speculation, but I think it fits the data ;)

Comment: @Yar thanks - I think it does fit the data.